# Does Install4j support Add-on installer for MAC

Tags: install4j

Does Install4j support Add-on installer for MAC? As for MAC only MyApplication.app file is installed so in case it supports then it shall update the file set bundled with Add-on installer only not the whole MyApplication.app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limitation for add-on installers regarding Mac OS X. However, this feature only works for installer media files, not for archive media files.

Comment: I have a MAC installer with media type single bundle. I need to create its Add-On installer. As on MAC Add-On installer support only folder type not single type so due to this I am facing two problem while installation :             1. It does not detect the installed main app automatically under installation location window unlike in case of  windows platform where it does the same automatically. 2. It installs the files under the selected directory only but it should have install under <selected_dir>/contents/java/app directory. Please advise on this how to resolve this.

Comment: I have no idea right away. Please ask another question for that, the comments on this answer are not suitable for this discussion.